# Creating a favourites list and sync

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview, file-io

I am creating a favourites list using custom listview.

```
-----------------------------------
 <Item_Name>   <favourite button>
-----------------------------------
```

There is onItemClickListener on the listView. Clicking on any position of listview takes us to a different intent that shows the details of that item.

Clicking on the favourite button the listview adds the item to favourite list. I plan to make an arraylist to save the ids of the items. This I want to save on the device itself and later save on the network database.

Please suggest which is the best way to do this..
1) should i use sqlite database or a text file? which one will be more efficient for my use?
2) is it important to sync data through ContentProvider? Or just fetching a list and simple json parsing would be suffiecient?

I have gone through many related questions but I am still confused. Please help.

Comment: Good Question, let the experts advice!

Answer (score 0):

1. I will suggest using simple sqlite database with one table because you can easily add some other information to it and maintain records in it if the user for example remove favourite item. Now comes to my mind the flag if the record was already synced to network could be usable. You can implement ContentProvider for this but i will suggest simply use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)and extend [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).
2. Of course, you can save ids to a text file as comma separated values, one per line or as you want, but adding some other info to ids would be problematic also as removing some value or editing. I will not suggest using JSON for the same reason of maintaining the text file.

Comment: i have used sqlite database to store the ids.. but what can i use instead of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

1-sqlite database more better than any thing for retrieving and setting or you can use XML structure and save it in xml file but as I say you sqlite more better and faster ..

2-for getting or sync data in your case you can use any thing simple you don't need big helper classes,

> I have my own library with it I can create any database and use it with 3
>   to 4 code line maximum , so when you setup something like that the text
>   file not in your work list .

**finally** if you want really my advice : do every thing you want with to top and better structure because if you set any future updates you will faced many problems and difficulties if you take short and simple way.